# Multirow Update Query with HTML table form

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, multirow

I have the following problem.I have an HTML form with multiple rows. Every row has 4 columns (ID,NAME,LASTNAME,EMAIL). I cannot figure out in my code which is the specific problem that is returned to me:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(name,lastname,email) VALUES ('.('Billly','Blueton1','bb5@phpeasystep.com'),('J' at line 1

I am trying to insert with a single submit query multiple updates. I think I am close to the solution but I am stuck because I am not expert in programming languages. Any help; it would be appreciated.

HERE IS MY CODE :

```
    <?php

   $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
   mysql_select_db("test");



$sql="SELECT * FROM test_mysql";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Count table rows
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

?>

<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<form name="form1" method="post" action="" >
<tr>
<td>
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">

<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>Id</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Lastname</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Email</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td align="center">
<? $id[]=$rows['id']; ?><?php echo $rows['id'];?>
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="name[]" type="text" id="name"  value='<?php echo $rows['name']; ?>'>
</td>
<td align="center"> 
<input name="lastname[]" type="text" id="lastname" value='<?php echo $rows['lastname']; ?>'>
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="email[]" type="text" id="email" value='<?php echo $rows['email']; ?>'>
</td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit1" value="ΕΝΗΜΕΡΩΣΗ"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>

<?php

 if(isset($_POST['name'])){
       foreach($_POST['name'] as $row=>$Name)
       {
           $id = intval($rows['id']);   
           $name = mysql_real_escape_string($Name);
           $lastname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname'][$row]);
           $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'][$row]);

           $row_data[]="('$name','$lastname','$email')"; 
            $implodeArray = implode(",", $row_data);

       }
    if(!empty($row_data)){
           $query = "UPDATE test_mysql (name,lastname,email)  VALUES ('.$implodeArray.') WHERE id='$id'" or die(mysql_error());
           $result1 = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
        }   
 }
?>
```

Comment: `i am stuck`: Where are you stuck? What error(s) do you get?

Comment: There is a `SET` missing in your update statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of problems with your code. You are doing the query wrong, and it looks like you are using some of the variables incorrectly. Also, you do not need `or die(mysql_error())` after defining your `$query` variable. Try this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['name'] as $i => $name) {

        $id = intval($_POST['id'][$i]);
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
        $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname'][$i]);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'][$i]);

        mysql_query("UPDATE test_mysql SET name='$name', lastname='$lastname', email='$email' WHERE id=$id") or die(mysql_error());
    }   
}

?>
```

And change your table in the while loop to this:

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) : ?>

<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <?php
            $id[] = $rows['id'];
            echo $rows['id'];
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <input name="name[]" type="text" id="name"  value="<?php echo $rows['name']; ?>" />
    </td>
    <td align="center"> 
        <input name="lastname[]" type="text" id="lastname" value="<?php echo $rows['lastname']; ?>" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <input name="email[]" type="text" id="email" value="<?php echo $rows['email']; ?> /">
    </td>
</tr>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: UPDATE test_mysql SET (name,lastname,email) VALUES (('Billly','Blueton34','bb5@phpeasystep.com'),('Jame','Campbell','jame@somewhere.com'),('Mark','Jackson','mark@phpeasystep.com'),('Linda','Travor','lin65@phpeasystep.com'),('Joey','Ford','fordloi@somewhere.com'),('Sidney','Gibson','gibson@phpeasystep.com')) WHERE id='0'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(name,lastname,email) VALUES (('Billly','Blueton34','bb5@phpeasystep.com'' at line 1

This is the result of the echo $query... Any clues????

Comment: @user2910800 Change your code to what I have given and try that. You are not writing a valid SQL query and you have other problems with your code. Just copy and paste exactly the two parts I have given and replace the corresponding parts in your original code.

Comment: you are my LEGEND...i really appreciate your help, it works perfectly!!! MANY THANKS!!!